# How to unit test a method with a `using` statement?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, idisposable, legacy-code

How can I write a unit test for a method that has a using statement?

For example let assume that I have a method `Foo`.

```
public bool Foo()
{
    using (IMyDisposableClass client = new MyDisposableClass())
    {
        return client.SomeOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

How can I test something like the code above?

Sometimes I choose not to use `using` statement and `Dispose()` an object manually.  I hope that someone will show me a trick I can use.

Comment: What is TDD? The only expansion I know of is Test-Driven Development.

Comment: It is Test Driven Development.

Comment: So your question is "How can I test-driven development something like the code above?"

Comment: Test-driven develop.  Cut some slack with the conjugation :)

Comment: Well, I was also trying to point out that you can't "test-driven develop" code that already exists. But that's been mentioned in several answers now.

Comment: The title is "How to TDD method with `using` statement?" but then you say "Sometimes I choose not to use `using` statement and `Dispose` an object manually." That only serves to confuse. Also, this doesn't look like TDD to me; you don't have a test but you have a method that you want to test. In TDD tests come first; there are no methods without tests. So it seems this is more about how to unit test that `Dispose` is called. So how about "How to unit test that `Dispose` is called?" Then the unambiguous answer is pass in the dependency `IMyDisposableClass` and mock. `new` is evil in testing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you construct the `IMyDisposableClass` using a factory (injected into the parent class) rather than using the new keyword, you can mock the `IMyDisposable` and do a verify on the dispose method call.

```
public bool Foo()
{
    using (IMyDisposableClass client = _myDisposableClassFactory.Create())
    {
        return client.SomeOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternately, you can use a virtual factory method, and test a specialization of that object that returns an appropriate mockable instance.  When looking at code, remember that the new operator is a static dependency - there are other good reasons to avoid its use in non-factory objects, too.

Comment: Can someone provide an example of what is meant by this answer.

Comment: @StephenPrice: In class constructor inject factory (IMyDisposableFactory MyDisposableFactory) then in public bool Foo()
{
    using (IMyDisposableClass client = MyDisposableFactory.CreateCl())
    {
        return client.SomeOtherMethod();
    }
}

Comment: 11 years later, I would say that your tests probably shouldn't test methods, they should test behaviours of the system. Outside in > inside out testing.

Answer (score 18):

If you already have your code and are asking how to test it, then you're not writing your tests first...so aren't really doing TDD.

However, what you have here is a dependency. So the TDD approach would be to use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection). This can be made easier using an [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container like [Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity/).

When doing TDD "properly", your thought processes should run as follows in this sort of scenario:

- I need to do a `Foo`
- For this I will rely on an external dependency that will implement an interface (new or pre-existing) of `IMyDisposableClass`
- Therefore I will inject an `IMyDisposableClass` into the class in which `Foo` is declared via its constructor

Then you would write one (or more) tests that fail, and only then would you be at the point where you were writing the `Foo` function body, and determine whether you needed to use a `using` block.

In reality you might well know that yes, you will use a `using` block. But part of the point of TDD is that you don't need to worry about that until you've proven (via tests) that you do need to use an object that requires this.

Once you've determined that you need to use a `using` block you would then want to write a test that fails - for example using something like [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) to set an expectation that `Dispose` will get called on a mock object that implements `IMyDisposableClass`.

For example (using Rhino Mocks to mock `IMyDisposableClass`).

```
[TestFixture]
public class When_calling_Foo
{
    [Test]
    public void Should_call_Dispose()
    {
        IMyDisposableClass disposable = MockRepository
                                        .GenerateMock<IMyDisposableClass>();

        Stuff stuff = new Stuff(disposable);

        stuff.Foo();

        disposable.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Dispose());
    }
}
```

Class in which your Foo function exists, with `IMyDisposableClass` injected as a dependency:

```
public class Stuff
{
    private readonly IMyDisposableClass _client;

    public Stuff(IMyDisposableClass client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public bool Foo()
    {
        using (_client)
        {
            return _client.SomeOtherMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

And the interface `IMyDisposableClass`

```
public interface IMyDisposableClass : IDisposable
{
    bool SomeOtherMethod();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry Richard but your answer is not very helpful. I've written a lot of DI code and used many different Inversion of Control containers including Unity.

I'm working on legacy code that has only integration tests.
I like mcintyre321 answer where he suggests to use a factory. It's very helpful I can implement it.

If you read my question completely you would read "Sometimes I choose not to use using statement and Dispose an object manually."

Comment: I have modified the question to make it clearer that this is testing existing code, not TDD.

Comment: TBH it's pretty much the same answer I gave, except I'd have the constructor of Stuff like
    Stuff(Func<IMyDisposableClass> myDisposableFactory)

Comment: @mcintyre: Do you do that for all injected dependencies, and then use the injected factory to instantiate your dependencies only when required?

Comment: @Richard, my original comment was written before you edited your answer with the code sample.  It's definitely helpful; however mcintyre321, was first. +1

Comment: @Richard, I only inject a factory Func (or a real Factory interface) as opposed to the dependency if the class has to manage the whole lifecycle of the dependency (e.g. create it and destroy it) or create multiple instances. See 'auto-generated-factories' in AutoFac 2 for a nice way for this to work (http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/NewInV2)

Comment: What happens when someone calls `Foo()` twice for the same instance of `Stuff`?

Comment: @Seph - If that was a requirement then my approach would not be a good one.

Answer (score 6):

Your question doesn't make sense. If you are using TDD, then you should already have a test for what you have written. Requirements, then tests, then design, then development. Either your code passes your tests, or it doesn't.

Now, if your question is how to unit test the above piece of code, then that's another question completely, and I think the other posters have answered it up there.

Sometimes I think there are more buzzwords than developers :)

Comment: Amen. It's incredible to watch people consistently struggle with the wrong tool (regex, LINQ) or the wrong approach (DDD) because it's "hot" and they just want to be "cool." Plus one.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapper methods like that aren't unit-testable, because you can't specify the relevant preconditions or post-conditions.

To make the method testable, you'll have to pass an `IMyDisposableClass` instance into the method or into the class hosting `Foo` (and make the host class itself implement `IDisposable`), so you can use a test double instead of the real thing to verify any interactions with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense. If you are doing TDD, then the method that you posted is *already* fully tested, otherwise it couldn't even exist in the first place. So, your question doesn't make sense.

If, on the other hand, the method that you posted does already exist, but isn't fully tested, then you aren't doing TDD anyway, and your question about TDD doesn't make sense, either.

In TDD, it is simply *impossible* for untested code to exist. Period.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the method signature to allow passing in a mock for unit testing. This would provide an alternative to using a factory, which would also need to be unit tested. DI into the method as opposed to the class constructor may be preferable here.

```
public bool Foo(IMyDisposableClass mock = null)
{
    using (IMyDisposableClass client = mock ?? new MyDisposableClass())
    {
        return client.SomeOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are testing Foo, then you should be looking at the output of Foo, not worrying about the disposal of the class it is using internally.

If you want to test `MyDisposableClass`' dispose method to see if it is working, that should be a separate unit test built against `MyDisposableClass`.

You don't need to unit test the `using { }` block, since that is part of the language.  You either trust that it's working, or don't use C#. :)  I don't see the need to write a unit test to verify that `Dispose()` is being called.

Comment: I don't want to test MyDisposableClass I want to mock it. Jeff Sternal and mcintyre321 bellow have good suggestions for me to try.

Comment: Nobody wants to test the using{} block.  The using{} block presents a dependency that can't be injected since the instantiation of an object using the using{} block must be done In-Line.  And since that dependency is typically to a persistence layer or some code that unmanaged at some point, it's important to DI it with a mock.  So the question is, how do you DI a Using{} block to mock out the dependency.

Answer (score -1):

Without a specification for Foo, how can we say how to test it?

1. Get the specification for Foo.
2. Write tests to ensure that it meets all specifications and requirements (or a reasonable subset- some functions could require practically infinite amounts of data to test).

I believe you have a second, implicit question in there - which is how to test that use of your MyDisposableClass correctly Disposes of the object when it is freed by exiting an using clause. This is a separate test issue, and shouldn't be combined with the test of Foo, since the specification of Foo shouldn't reference implementation specific details such as the use of your MyDisposabeClass.

I think the  other posters have answered this question, so I won't further elaborate.