# Shall I use using statement or dependency injection for web service client

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dependency-injection

I've recently written the a pieces of codes that involve Soap Web service call.

Example codes as below is perfectly working fine.   The only problem is I couldn't do unit test the code as I use 'using' statement. I can use Constructor based Dependency Injection using MS Unity dependency injector.

The question is whether I shall use dependency injector for this or not. The reason of using 'Using' statement is I want to dispose the object after method called.

```
private ResultSet GetLookupMailingData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new NDataAccessSoapClient())
            {
                var result = client.GetLookupData(XMLLookupDataTypes.xldtMailings, "");
                return Deserialize<ResultSet>(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new ResultSet();
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unit test a method with a \`using\` statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953644/how-to-unit-test-a-method-with-a-using-statement)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a factory that's injected instead. Thus you can mock the factory to return a mock client and setup expectations on that. For example:

```
interface INDataAccessSoapClientFactory
{
    NDataAccessSoapClient CreateClient();
}

class Lookup
{
    private INDataAccessSoapClientFactory factory;

    public Lookup(INDataAccessSoapClientFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    private ResultSetGetLookupMailingData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = factory.CreateClient())
            {
                var result = client.GetLookupData(XMLLookupDataTypes.xldtMailings, "");
                return Deserialize<ResultSet>(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           return new ResultSet();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The CreateClient in INDataAccessSoapClientFactory should return an interface and not a concrete class or it can't be mocked, isn't it?